# Change visibility on Compile

Tags: java, ant, obfuscation

I am using Apache Ant to Build my java project into 1 big Jar File.
I would like to know if there is any way i could change visibility(from private/protected > PUBLIC) all classes, fields and methods?

So in my source code i would still have different kind of visibility, but final product(the jar, that i create by Ant) will have everything open to public.

I have checked the java obfuscators(proguard, yGuard) but they don't seem to allow such possibility.

Can this be done? Can anybody help?

Comment: Should be doable via simple byte code manipulation. The obvious question is why on earth would you want to do this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Code what you want as final product.

Comment: Is there any guides how to make such byte code manipulations? I am trying to do it to have possibility to see and modify every value without using debugging.

Comment: You already can, with reflection.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to do this making public everything (and don't want to use reflection) then you can use [ant replace](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html). You just create a new directory like "temporarysrc" and copy all of you java files there, and then call this task + compile the result with javac:

```
<replace dir="${tmpsrc}" token="private" value="public">
      <include name="**/*.java"/>
</replace>
```

This will be not bulletproof, because if you have some methods, variables that contains the word "private" that will mess up everything. Moreover if you have classes with multiple classes, then there will be multiple public classes, that is an error.

The advantage of this is that, if you include the created jar in a project, you can see the fields and methods from the IDE too.

**Just for the record: this is only for experimenting:)**